# Range Filters on doc_count on a Term Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "categories_agg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categories",
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For getting aggregations on a particular fields I used the query given above. It works fine and gives a result like:

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 77445,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "categories_agg": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 794,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 148316,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Restaurants",
          "doc_count": 25071
        },
        {
          "key": "Shopping",
          "doc_count": 11233
        },
        {
          "key": "Food",
          "doc_count": 9250
        },
        {
          "key": "Beauty & Spas",
          "doc_count": 6583
        },
        {
          "key": "Health & Medical",
          "doc_count": 5121
        },
        {
          "key": "Nightlife",
          "doc_count": 5088
        },
        {
          "key": "Home Services",
          "doc_count": 4785
        },
        {
          "key": "Bars",
          "doc_count": 4328
        },
        {
          "key": "Automotive",
          "doc_count": 4208
        },
        {
          "key": "Local Services",
          "doc_count": 3468
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can filter the aggregation in such a way I can get the buckets within a particular range on `doc_count` of each bucket?

e.g. using a range filter for `doc_count` where max is `25000` and min is `5000` should give me

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 77445,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "categories_agg": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 794,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 148316,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Shopping",
          "doc_count": 11233
        },
        {
          "key": "Food",
          "doc_count": 9250
        },
        {
          "key": "Beauty & Spas",
          "doc_count": 6583
        },
        {
          "key": "Health & Medical",
          "doc_count": 5121
        },
        {
          "key": "Nightlife",
          "doc_count": 5088
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have been looking answer for the same question. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve the problem by buckets_selector .
    We can filter count in the script .

````
```
"aggs": {
    "categories_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cel_num",
        "size": 5000,
        "min_doc_count":1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_bucket_selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "lang":"expression",
              "inline": "count>5000 && count <10000"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution for filtering by minimum doc_count (only) from [Elasticsearch filter aggregations on minimal doc count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843712/elasticsearch-filter-aggregations-on-minimal-doc-count). To save you looking it up:

```
 aggs: {
    field1: {
        terms: {
            field: 'field1',
            min_doc_count: 1000
        },
```