# Elasticsearch Query (Console) - Post Filter Based On Count From Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregated query that I am running in Elasticsearch. The results look good, however, I want to add a post filter by returning only results with a count greater than 100. Here's the query:

```
GET /_search
{
  "size": 0,
   "query" :
      {
          "query_string":
          {
            "fields" : ["error_message"],
            "query" : "login AND failed"
          }
      },
  "aggs":
  {
    "group_by_id":
    {
      "terms":
      {
        "field": "Id",
        "size": 1000 
      },
      "aggs":
      {
        "group_by_date":
        {
          "date_range":
          {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "ranges":
            [
              {
                "from": "now-6h",
                "to": "now"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results look as follows:

```
       {
          "key": "12",
          "doc_count": 89388,
          "group_by_date": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "2018-09-20T12:48:04.200-2018-09-20T18:48:04.200",
                "from": 1537447684200,
                "from_as_string": "2018-09-20T12:48:04.200",
                "to": 1537469284200,
                "to_as_string": "2018-09-20T18:48:04.200",
                "doc_count": 50
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

I would like to only return results for the second doc_count being greater than 100. So this returned example would not be displayed.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843712/elasticsearch-filter-aggregations-on-minimal-doc-count) question. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: This is perfect, I wasn't able to find this from a previous search