# ElasticSearch aggregation in case of minimal document count

Tags: elasticsearch

(This is a similar question to [Elasticsearch filter aggregations on minimal doc count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843712/elasticsearch-filter-aggregations-on-minimal-doc-count))

Consider I have a following list:

- A
- A
- A
- B
- B

I can easily perform aggregation by the title, which results in:

- A (3x)
- B (2x)

The question above deals with removing results which are less then `min_doc_count`. In this case for value of `2`, this would end up like:

- A (3x)
- B

In my case `min_doc_count` does not help, because I still want to keep these results, but ungrouped. Eg for minCount 2, I would like to have following result:

- A (3x)
- B
- B

Is this achievable with Elastic aggregations?

Comment: This is something that can easily be achieved with a [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) but it'd be like shooting a fly with a bazooka. I'm always surprised at the infinite originality of some use cases our there. I'm curious why someone would want to see such results (grouped + ungrouped), but that's another story. What you could do is still use the terms aggregation and when showing your results, you'd show B twice instead of once if doc_count<=2.

Comment: 'you'd show B twice instead of once if doc_count<=2' - this wouldn't work, it is kind of B_1 and B_2 grouped by B. will try the scripted metric. thanks!

Comment: What allows you to distinguish between B_1 and B_2? if that's just a field, then you can use `terms` aggregation with a script instead of just a field. In that script you can build up a synthetic field composed of two fields (B and 1) and aggregate on that value. That would do the trick

Comment: I am still not sure how to achieve that :) B_1 and B_2 are distinguished by their "parent id" field, which is B. I basically don't want to keep the _1 in aggregation, I just want to aggregate only if there is `> n` documents in aggregation, otherwise leave out unagregated.

Comment: And A would be aggregated the same way? Can you provide just a few sample documents so I can show you what I mean?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/b370ee0c47b0fe37db2c32189ac07612 tried to create a better example

Comment: Thanks, I see. I thought it was a bit different, then terms with script won't help in this case